# Setting value of a column for each multiindex in repeating order

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have a dataframe `df` with 60 dates, and for each date there are 400 IDs. Looking like this:

```
 Date       ID
 2018-01-01   1000
 2018-01-01   1001
 ....
 2018-02-01   1000
 2018-02-01   1001
```

Now what I would like to do is to create a third column. The value of which is the same for all ID's on a given date. I created a seperate one-column dataframe `df_value` for this that has 60 random generated values in descending order:

```
     Value 
     350
     340
     337
     323
     ...
```

In the end it should look like this:

```
 Date       ID        Value
 2018-01-01   1000     350
 2018-01-01   1001     350
 ....
 2018-02-01   1000     340
 2018-02-01   1001     340
```

I tried creating a groupby dataframe with `Date` and `ID` as indexes to later add the values in the `Placeholder` column. But couldn't really figure out where to go from there:

```
                     Placeholder
 Date       ID
 2018-01-01   1000       1
 2018-01-01   1001       1
 ....
 2018-02-01   1000       1
 2018-02-01   1001       1
```

Probably the groupby idea is a death end. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my bad I should have initially mentioned that the values are randomly generated. The distance between them is not always 10. So I think I have to find a way to reference `df_value` with `iloc` somehow or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), only necessary default index in `df_value`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('date').ngroup().map(df_value['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that something like this may work for you:

```
for i,date in enumerate(df.Date.drop_duplicates()): 
  df.loc[df[df.Date == date].index, 'value'] = value[i]
```